# parsing file in JSON loop using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a [JSON file](http://jsfiddle.net/7q0trbLz/1/) where I am parsing the data, below is what I have tried and did not workout.

```
response = requests.post('https://satest.com', headers=headers, data=data)
response1=response.json()
print(response1[0].evtName)
for value in response1:
        if value['evtName'] = re.match(r'\b(\w*TY-AB12\w*)\b', "TY-AB12"): #I want to loop in json Exactly match the evtName with TY-AB12
              print(response1[value]['evtName'])
```

Objective : to loop through the json and output all the value of `evtName` , `evt` and `PG` which has `TY-AB12` associated in the `evtname` (TY-AB12 sample app2 url)

Can anyone help here on how to proceed here.

Answer (score 2):

### Simple soution

If you want all items, that have their `evtName` starting with`TY-AB12` in their `evtName` just look for basic string inclusion

```
values = response1["data"]
for value in values:
    if value['evtName'].startswith('TY-AB12'):
        print(value)

{'evt': 85, 'evtName': 'TY-AB12 sample app1 url', 'Config': {'CG': 'TTFG', 'PG': '0002'}}
{'evt': 86, 'evtName': 'TY-AB12 sample app2 url', 'Config': {'CG': 'TTFG', 'PG': '0000'}}
```

---

### Alternatives :

- `evtName` contains the pattern : `if 'TY-AB12' in value['evtName']:`
- `evtName` matches a regex : `if re.match('TY-AB12', value['evtName']):` (`fullmatch` also exists)

---

Given a `response1` that is

```
response1 = {
    "name": "testappsa",
    "data": [{"evt": 85, "evtName": "TY-AB12 sample app1 url", "Config": {"CG": "TTFG", "PG": "0002"}},
             {"evt": 85, "evtName": "TY-AB34 sample app1 url", "Config": {"CG": "TTKL", "PG": "0006"}},
             {"evt": 86, "evtName": "TY-AB12 sample app2 url", "Config": {"CG": "TTFG", "PG": "0000"}},
             {"evt": 88, "evtName": "TY ALL - TY-AB12ALL app3 url", "Config": {"CG": "TFFY", "PG": "000"}}]
}
```

Comment: No I dont have a dict element thats why I did `response1=response.json()`

Comment: my response looks something like this http://jsfiddle.net/xgo9n243/2/
How should I iterate for this ??

Comment: @Thomas you may understand what the dict is, you just need to using "data" key to get the values look my edit

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over all the events and check if the evtName contains TY-AB12. if it does then just print the values you are interested in.

```py
import json
with open('test.dat') as test_data:
    json_data = json.load(test_data)
    for event in json_data:
        if 'TY-AB12' in event['evtName']:
            print(event['evt'], event['evtName'], event['Config']['PG'])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
85 TY-AB12 sample app1 url 0002
86 TY-AB12 sample app2 url 0000
88 TY ALL - TY-AB12ALL app3 url 000
```

Comment: I cannot use start with because if you notice the JSON there is another evtName which should be in the expected output `TY ALL - TY-AB12ALL app3 url` so will regex be a better option here ? I guess

Comment: In that case just use in

Comment: if I do `json_data = json.load(test_data)` It gives error as `return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: This is in illustration, where i am loading up the json data. You already have the json_data so you would just do  `for event in response1:` since you already have the json object. you can just ignore the lines before the for loop.

Comment: okay is this step necessary ? `response1=response.json()` because if I directly work with `response1` as you said it gives me error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204800/discussion-between-thomas-and-chris-doyle).